# Unable to calculate angle between two points on Earth

Tags: distance, coordinates

I am unable to reproduce correct calculation of angular distance of the globe.

I selected two point near my home on Google Earth:

[image]

and measured the distance between them by the ruler tool.

Distance in meters is approximately `100` and distance in arcseconds is reported by program as `3.19`

I have calculated this formula

```
(100/6371008.8)/2/Pi *360*60*60
```

and found it equals to `3.23` which is close to the value, reported by Google Earth and the difference is probably caused by geoid shape.

Now I tried to calculate the same value trough vectors on the computer and encountered much bigger error

[image]

As you see, first I converted geographic coordinates to 3D cartesian ones and then calculate an angle between two vectors by normalizing inner product. Unfortunately, the result is `2.18`, which is much more wrong.

Intermediate value also presented.

Looks like the main problem is calculating inverse cosine for the value, close to `1`. Is this true?

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for finding the distance (angular or Earth's surface) between two points. Which formula are you using?

I'm not sure how you've turned lat/lon 2D coordinates into x, y, z 3D coordinates. Have you tried taking the Euclidean distance and checking that it is reasonable?

As I'm sure you know, some spherical calculations can break down over very short distances.